# Counting number of words in char array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am working on an algorithm that will count the number of words in a char array. So far it seems to not work the way it should. When a character is reach and it is not whitespace, it should be considered to be part of a word. Once you reach white space, we are not in a word anymore. For example, "Hello World" is two words because of the space between "hello" and "world".

Code:

```
for(int l = 0; l < count; l++){
        if(isalpha(letters[l]) && !in_word){
            num_words++;
            in_word = true;     
        }else{
            in_word = false;
        }
    }
```

sample input: 
aaaaa bbb aaa lla bub www

sample output:
13 words

desired output: 6 words

Possible answer:

```
for(int l = 0; l < count; l++){
        if(isalpha(letters[l]) && !in_word){
            num_words++;
            in_word = true;     
        }else if(!isalpha(letters[l])){
            in_word = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you mean count the number of *letters*?

Comment: no. I already figured out how to do that. I am trying to figure out how to count the number of words.

Comment: What is the size of the array?

Comment: How do you define a word?  How is in_word initialized?

Comment: Whats the initial state of in_word?

Answer (score 2):

Step through that code (in a debugger, in your head/on paper).

Given the input "abc def"

Assuming `in_word` = false initially

- The first character is 'a', `in_word` is false, so `num_words++`, `in_word=true`
- The next character is 'b', `in_word` is true, so `in_word=false`

Hopefully you will see what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

easy way to do this: trim the string, count the spaces, add 1

Comment: What about multiple spaces between words?

Comment: Is that not a part of trimming the string?

Comment: I assumed you meant removing spaces at the beginning and end of the string. If your "trim" means removing double spaces, then this works.

Comment: Nomenclature issue: perhaps the better phrase is "sanitize the string"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get nice handling of newlines, spaces punctuation etc you could use a regex. You may even be able to adapt this to work correctly with utf-8 strings too. However it requires C++11 support.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s ("this subject has a submarine as a subsequence");
  std::smatch m;
  std::regex e ("\\b(\w*)\\b")

  int count = 0;
  while (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
    ++count;
    s = m.suffix().str();
  }

  std::cout<<"Number of matches = "<<count<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```